# Embed image with a link using phpmailer from a private website cannot be seen by the recipient

Tags: php, image, hyperlink, phpmailer, embed

Using phpmailer I need to build an email with an embedded image which has a link.
At the body of the message it is trivial to include

```
<a href="link"><img src="URL of the image to embed" /></a>
```

My problem is that that URL is protected by username and password so the recipient of the email cannot see the image, just a broken thumbnail with the link.
I tried using file_get_contents() as I read in other questions but didn't get the solution.

Comment: You could place the image in another folder outside the public area and echo it from an include or similar; could work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i attach an image using Phpmailer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095285/how-can-i-attach-an-image-using-phpmailer)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I already bought that but it is not the idea.

Comment: @rickdenhaan $mail->AddEmbeddedImage ASFAIK it is not possible to add a hyperlink and also I cannot place the image in the right place of the body of the message

Comment: @dstonek yes it is, see the accepted answer on that question. First call `AddEmbeddedImage` with the path to the file and give it an identifier via the second argument. Then you can add an `<img src="cid:foo" />` to your message body wherever you want it, where `foo` should match the identifier you provided to `AddEmbeddedImage`. That `<img />` *can* be inside an `<a />` tag.

Comment: This was enough to get it.  `$mail->AddEmbeddedImage(“/path/to/image/“,”img”);`
`<a href="url">Text <br /><img src="cid:img” /></a>`. Thanks!